# windows form event handling

Tags: .net, windows, c++-cli

I am totally a newbie in windows programming and I have got a textbox which is to display text when the main gui *i.e form1* is resized but the event is not firing. Any pointers as th why this is happening would appreciated.

```
private: System::Void Form1_Resize(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

             //int newFormWidth = this->Width;
             textBox1->Text = "Obi";
         }
```

Comment: The Click event is fired when you click the form client area, handle the SizeChanged event to get notified when its size changes.

Comment: that was a little error..it is Resize event I am referring to.

Comment: Is the handler actually hooked up to the event? Having a method implemented doesn't automatically mean that someone is calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the region that has the Windows Form Designer generated code you have an InitializeComponent method.Check to see if you have the handler hooked up to your event. it should look something like this.

```
this->SizeChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_SizeChanged);
```

Comment: added that but I still get an error in which Form1_SizeChanged is an undeclared identifier